# Picker does not render with-in react-native-elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I'm trying to add the Picker element (so I can have a dropdown menu) to the Header component (the header was imported from the react-native-elements library) yet I cannot see it and theres no errors that I can see, any help would be appreciated.

I have successfully added a vector icon so I know the header component is working as intended, yet still following the documentation I can't see any it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Picker,
    ListView
} from 'react-native';
import CoinCell from './js/Components/CoinCell/CoinCell';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { getCryptocurrencyData } from './js/NetworkHandler'

export default class CoinCheckerRN extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([]),
    };

    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
    this._getCoinData = this._getCoinData.bind(this);
    this._renderPicker = this._renderPicker.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._getCoinData();
  }

  _getCoinData() {
    getCryptocurrencyData().then(function(result) {

      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
      this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(result),
        jsonData: result
      });
    }.bind(this))
  }


  _renderRow(data) {
    return (
        <CoinCell coinName={data.name} coinPrice={data.price_gbp} coinPercentageChange={data.percent_change_24h}></CoinCell>        )
  }

  _renderPicker() {
    return (<Picker
        selectedValue={'test'}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
      <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    </Picker>)
  }

  _renderHeader() {
    return (
        <Header
            leftComponent={<Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.language}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
              <Picker.Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
            </Picker>}
            rightComponent={{ icon: 'refresh', color: '#FFF' }}
            innerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#03A9F4'}}
            outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#03A9F4'}}
        />)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          {this._renderHeader()}
          <ListView
              enableEmptySections
              ref={'resultListView'}
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this._renderRow}
              style={{paddingTop: 64}}
              renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
          />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a working example? You can use somwthing like https://codesandbox.io/ to share it.

Comment: What exactly of an example would you like? A specific component or the entire screen?, Picker doesn't seem to be available in the React library so that URL wouldn't render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a pretty similar problem before and defining the picker height/width fixed it.

Comment: Added a picker height/width as a style object to the component, still no luck.